# toggle class of multiple elements based on clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code looks something like :-

```
<div id="boxgallery" class="boxgallery" data-effect="effect-3">
            <div class="panel"><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Image 2" />
                <button class="button overlay-launcher" id="pop2">
                    link
                </button>
                <div id="pop2" class="overlay-background"></div>
                <div id="pop2" class="overlay-content">
                    <button id="pop2" class="overlay-close">Close overlay Window</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel"><img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Image 3" />
                <button class="button overlay-launcher" id="pop3">
                    link
                </button>>
                <div id="pop3" class="overlay-background"></div>
                <div id="pop3" class="overlay-content">
                    <button id="pop3" class="overlay-close">Close overlay Window</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
                <button class="button overlay-launcher" id="pop1">
                    link
                </button>>
                <div id="pop1" class="overlay-background"></div>
                <div id="pop1" class="overlay-content">
                    <button id="pop1" class="overlay-close">Close overlay Window</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel"><img src="img/4.jpg" alt="Image 4" />
                <button class="button overlay-launcher" id="pop4">
                    link
                </button>>
                <div id="pop4" class="overlay-background"></div>
                <div id="pop4" class="overlay-content">
                    <button id="pop4" class="overlay-close">Close overlay Window</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

I was trying :-

```
$(function() {
                $(".overlay-launcher").click(function() {
                    $(".overlay-content,.overlay-background").toggleClass("active");
                });
            });
```

but it would work only if i have only one of those
or if i write the jquery for each one separately

what i want to achieve is if i click on the launcher for the pop1 then the content and background of the 1st overlay should appear

same for the rest

the nearest I found was this [Single function to toggle multiple divs inside other divs individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348450/single-function-to-toggle-multiple-divs-inside-other-divs-individually?rq=1)

but it doesn't really solve the problem in my specific case I,
I ahve to toggle the active class based on the class of the element

EDIT:
CSS goes like this:-

```
.overlay-background {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: .50;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.overlay-content {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #222;
    display: none;
    height: 240px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -120px 0 0 -160px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 320px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.overlay-background .active,
.overlay-content .active {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the 2 things that needs to be done to make it work

- In css,

  ```
  .overlay-background.active, .overlay-content.active {
      display: block;
  }
  ```
- In Javascript,

  ```
  $(".overlay-launcher").click(function () {
      $('.overlay-content,.overlay-background').removeClass("active");
      $(this).siblings('.overlay-content,.overlay-background').addClass("active");
  });

  $('.overlay-close').on('click', function(){
      $('.overlay-content,.overlay-background').removeClass("active");
  });
  ```

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sachin_puthran/ssmstjvu/7/

Comment: Nice find!  I was mocking it in jsfiddle and missed that.

Comment: sorry, probably they were left from the 100ds of trials and errors I performed

Comment: I see the bug in your styles.. There should not be any space between `active` and `overlay-*` since they are on the same element `div` here -> `.overlay-background .active` and `.overlay-content .active`... check this working fiddle with your styles https://jsfiddle.net/sachin_puthran/ssmstjvu/3/

Comment: @Sachin thanks for the help, though i'll still need a way to remove the active class

Comment: `$('.overlay-content,.overlay-background').removeClass("active");` this removes the `active` class when another `link` button is clicked. The click handler is removing the `active` class from all the `overlay-content` and `overlay-background` divs and then sets `active` to the siblings of the `link` button thats clicked

Comment: Problem is i can't click on any other link if i can't close the overlay :/

Comment: You could add another function to remove the active class once the close button is clicked.. check this update.. https://jsfiddle.net/sachin_puthran/ssmstjvu/5/

Comment: Thanks @Sachin why don't you edit it in your answer so i can accept it as a solution

Comment: I have edited my answer with the required changes that needs to be done.. Thanks @ustone07

Answer (score 1):

You should not have multiple elements in your page with the same `id` like that. `id` values should be unique within a particular page.

Also note other syntax errors:

```
</button>>
</button>>
$(".overlay-launcher,")
```

Comment: It is definitely part of the answer. Not sure what else he will have to do in addition to this though.

Comment: sorry, probably they were left from the 100ds of trials and errors I performed