# How can I reveal the video that has been clicked using IDs in HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I've tried this but the 2 js functions don't work. I want it to show an iframe and hide the title when the button is press, just since there are more than one iframes to show, I need a scalable system using the unique IDs of each iframe. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="000">
<div id="video">     
  <iframe style="position:relative;top:0;width:100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KfDB9e_cO4k" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="title">
  <h3>Video 1</h3>
  </div>
  <button id='000' onclick="getId(this.id);showVideo();">Show</button>
</div>

<div id="111">
<div id="video">     
  <iframe style="position:relative;top:0;width:100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6dGYVKt1zw4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="title">
  <h3>Video 2</h3>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id='111' onclick="getId(this.id);showVideo();">Show</button>
</div>
</html>

<script>
function getId(clicked_id) {
   return clicked_id;
}

function showVideo() {
for (clicked_id) {
    document.getElementById('video').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('title').style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#video {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Iam gonna give you some tips and directions which should make it easy for your to achieve your goal by yourself. 1) Your onclick does not need 2 functions. 1 function is enough. Using event.target.id you can get the id of clicked element. 2) Its much better to add/remove class than doing style.display, etc. You can create a simple class and add it to the parent div if user clicked the button. 3) Toggling between iframes is not hard, for direction you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729141/toggle-class-of-multiple-elements-based-on-clicked-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the code below.

```js
      const showVide = (id) => {
        const yt_frame = document.getElementById("youtube_frame");
        yt_frame.setAttribute("src", `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}`);
        yt_frame.style.display = "unset";
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>  
    <iframe id="youtube_frame" style="position:relative;top:0;width:100%;display:none" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <h2>SOME TITLE</h2>
    <button onclick="showVide('bSOqMqMzN4Q')">Show</button>
    
    <h2>SOME TITLE</h2>
    <button onclick="showVide('jYOfvbD8HQ0')">Show</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can list videos dynamically with any backend, for eg: `PHP`.
**If you are using `PHP`**, then you can add following code instead of show button and title list.

```sh
<?php
  $videolist = array(
    array(
        "title"=>"Vishnu Stuti",
        "ytid"=>"bSOqMqMzN4Q"
      ),
    array(
       "title"=>"Visnu Stuti",
        "ytid"=>"jYOfvbD8HQ0"
    )
  );
  //ABOVE CODE WILL BE DYNAMIC, IF YOU USE ANY DATABASE, RIGHT NOW ITS JUST FOR EXAMPLE, SO IT IS     HARDCODED.
  foreach($videolist as $vid){
    echo "
      <h2>{$vid['title']}</h2>
      <button onclick='showVide(`{$vid['ytid']}`)'>SHOW</button>
    ";
  }  
?>
```